# Soboleve's and Gagliardo Inequality

Tags: sobolev-spaces

[image]

[image]

i am not understanding how he used Holder's inequality  to further steps

can some explain me how he got (1) and (2)

Comment: Do you know the generalized Hölder inequality?

Comment: @MaikUrban...no sir i totally confusing here

Comment: Then [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder's_inequality#Generalization_of_H%C3%B6lder's_inequality) might be helpful